# Idiomatic API Authentication flow with ASWebAuthentication and Combine

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, swiftui

I'm working on an app to display statistics based on user data from a third-party service's API. The authentication flow for the service's API that I wrote works, but some parts of it feel a bit awkward, so I want to make sure I'm holding Combine and SwiftUI correctly.

Some notes and specific questions:

- `readFromKeychain` and `writeFromKeychain` are convenience wrappers around `SecItemAdd` and friends.
- The API has two different OAuth flows. I believe only one is allowed for apps in production, but the other is more convenient during development, which is why `Constants.signInFlow` exists. Maybe I'll be allowed to use both and can offer users a choice.
- That `cancellables` seems really gross to me.
- The `url.removingPercentEncoding?...` bit *is* really gross. I get the callback url as `appName:%23myauthenticationcode`; what's the best way to handle that?
- Error handling is nonexistent. Would it be better to not have `signIn()` return `AnyPublisher<Bool,Never>` in favor of `AnyPublisher<URL, Error>`? I wanted the bool variant because I want `refreshToken()` to be easy to use in a more general `fetchURL` function, but maybe it makes more sense to separate out handling of errors during initial authentication from handling refresh token errors.

This is ContentView.swift:

```swift
import Combine
import SwiftUI

var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

func tokenExists() -> Bool {
    switch Constants.signInFlow {
    case .implicit:
        return readFromKeychain(account: Constants.implicitAccessToken) != nil
    case .authorizationCode:
        return readFromKeychain(account: Constants.authorizationCode) != nil
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isLoggedIn: Bool = tokenExists()

    var body: some View {
        if isLoggedIn {
            Text("ItemsView() goes here")
        } else {
            // this is normally a separate file
            VStack {
                Text("Welcome! Please sign in.")
                Button {
                    NetworkingController.shared.signIn()
                        .sink { Bool in
                            isLoggedIn = Bool
                        }
                        .store(in: &cancellables)
                } label: {
                    Text("Sign In")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Constants.swift`:

```
enum SignInFlow {
    case implicit, authorizationCode
}
 
enum Constants{
    static let signInFlow: SignInFlow = .implicit
}
```

And then I've got `NetworkingController.swift`:

```swift
import AuthenticationServices
import Combine
import Foundation

final class NetworkingController: NSObject, ObservableObject, ASWebAuthenticationPresentationContextProviding {
    static let shared = NetworkingController()

    func presentationAnchor(for _: ASWebAuthenticationSession) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
        return ASPresentationAnchor()
    }

    func signIn(url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<URL, Error> {
        return
            Future<URL, Error> { promise in
                let authSession = ASWebAuthenticationSession(url: url, callbackURLScheme: Constants.appName, completionHandler: { url, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        promise(.failure(error))
                    } else if let url = url {
                        promise(.success(url))
                    }
                })

                authSession.presentationContextProvider = self
                authSession.prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession = true
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    authSession.start()
                }
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    func implicitSignInFlow() -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
        signIn(url: Endpoints.requestImplicitAccessToken())
            .map { $0.absoluteString }
            .replaceError(with: "")
            .map { url in
                if url.isEmpty {
                    return false
                }
                let token = url.removingPercentEncoding?.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "&="))[1]

                saveToKeychain(info: token!, infoName: Constants.implicitAccessToken)
                return true
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    func signIn() -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
        if Constants.signInFlow == .implicit {
            return implicitSignInFlow()
        }
        return Just(false).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    func refreshToken() -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
        if Constants.signInFlow == .implicit {
            return implicitSignInFlow()
        }
        return Just(false).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your time in reading this; I look forward to your feedback!